# Adding multiple fields for multiple feature classes in a single geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, python-2.7

I am trying to add multiple fields to a list of feature classes in a geodatabase for NextGEN911.  I am having trouble executing this line of code because I am getting the following error

```
#Import arcpy and allow overwrite
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set the environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = "Z:\\\\ESInet\\PracticeESINet\\Practice.gdb"

#This returns a list of FeatureClasses in teh top of the level geodatabase
FcList = ["DaviePSAP", "DavieEMS", "DavieFire", "DaviePolice", "DavieSheriff"]

#Add all mandatory fields for all feature classes in .gdb using a loop
for fc in FcList:
    # The " " inputs mean just use defaults
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "sourceOFData", "TEXT", "", "", "75", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "Source of Last Edit Date", "DATE", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "uploadAuthority", "TEXT", "", "", "75", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "effectiveDate", "DATE", "","", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "expirationDate", "DATE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "county", "TEXT", "", "", "75", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "state", "TEXT", "", "", "2", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "country", "TEXT", "", "", "2", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "agencyID", "TEXT", "", "", "100", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "serviceURI", "TEXT", "", "", "254", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "serviceURN", "TEXT", "", "", "", "254", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "serviceNumber", "TEXT", "", "", "15", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "agencyVCardURI", "TEXT", "", "", "254", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "displayName", "TEXT", "", "", "60", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "comments", "TEXT", "", "", "100", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "gcLabel", "TEXT", "", "", "150", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")


if fc in FcList == "DaviePSAP":
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "sourcePSAPUnqID", "TEXT", "", "", "254", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

FCList2 = [ "DavieEMS", "DavieFire", "DaviePolice", "DavieSheriff"]

for fc in FCList2:
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "sourceUnqID", "TEXT", "", "", "254", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

print "Add field is successful"`
```

```
Error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users//Desktop/AddfieldsDiagnostic.py", line 19, in <module>
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "Source of Last Edit Date", "DATE", "", "", "", "True", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 3435, in AddField
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Add Field). Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of NULLABLE | NON_NULLABLE.
```

I have previously referred back to a older post that solved this issue by replacing the Nullable strings with "True", but that did not work either.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I am also running into this error:TypeError: AddField() takes at most 10 arguments (11 given)

Comment: Is there a way to overcome this or should I simply create a new script using similar syntax for the other fields?

Answer (score 1):

Include parameter names instead of empty strings to be sure you are providing the correct one:

`arcpy.AddField_management(in_table=fc, field_name="sourceOFData", field_type="TEXT",field_length=75)`.

Note that `Field length` should be data type `LONG` not `string` (no quotes surrounding 75) see Add [Field](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-field.htm) help.

This is incorrect syntax: `if fc in FcList == "DaviePSAP":`

Place the if within the for loop:

```
    ...
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "gcLabel", "TEXT", "", "", "150", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    if fc == "DaviePSAP":
        #do something
```